# Set a part of the partitioning primary key as UNIQUE

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, database-partitioning

I have a postgres table `A` which has 3 columns: `a1`, `a2`, `a3`.

The columns `a1` and `a2` make a compound primary key.
`a1` as used a the partition key.

And at the same time the column `a2` should have a non-repeatable value. When I try to set `a2` as a UNIQUE I get an error: `unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns`.

Is there any way to tell the DB to check that a new entry has a `a1` value different from the previous ones?

Answer (score 0):

To keep track of the uniqueness of the values in column a2, make a separate table. Each unique value of a2 will be kept in this table together with the accompanying a1 value.

```
CREATE TABLE a2_uniqueness (
    a2_value <datatype> NOT NULL,
    a1_value <datatype> NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (a2_value)
);
```

Before adding or changing data in your primary partitioned table, provide a trigger function that verifies the uniqueness of a2 values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_a2_uniqueness()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.a2 IS NOT NULL THEN
        -- Check if the a2 value already exists in the auxiliary table
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a2_uniqueness WHERE a2_value = NEW.a2) THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Duplicate value in column a2';
        END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The main partitioned table should have triggers that call the check_a2_uniqueness function before inserting or changing entries.

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_check_a2_uniqueness
BEFORE INSERT ON a
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION check_a2_uniqueness();

CREATE TRIGGER before_update_check_a2_uniqueness
BEFORE UPDATE ON a
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION check_a2_uniqueness();
```

With this strategy, you can keep the partitioning based on a1 while requiring uniqueness from a2.You must also properly manage the auxiliary table a2_uniqueness, taking inserts, updates, and deletions into account.